# How to remove WhatsApp contact from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, button, whatsapp

I'm using WordPress. The designer put a WhatsApp button that shows on the entire website. Any idea where I can find that snip of code to remove it? I checked the plugins, and I'm sure it is not a plugin.

This is what I see when I inspect the element. Any help please?

```
<div id="whatsapp_desktop" style="
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 11px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 40px;
">
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+6&amp;text=Merhabalar, Özel Bilgi Almak İstiyorum."><i class="fab fa-whatsapp" style="font-size: 50px;color: #3bc5aa;margin-right: 10px;"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the page link that this button contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `important`:

```
display:none!important;
```